# Sequential Scan Used Over Index Scan on More Restrictive Predicate

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, database-administration

`select version()`: `PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit`

I have two tables:

```
create table if not exists cover.covering_s2_cell_ids (
  covering_id int references cover.coverings(id) on delete cascade,
  s2_cell_id bigint,
  s2_cell_min bigint,
  s2_cell_max bigint,
  primary key (covering_id, s2_cell_id)
);


create table if not exists tiles.tileset_segment_counts (
  tileset_id int references tiles.tilesets(id) on delete cascade,
  s2_cell_id bigint not null,
  segments jsonb not null,
  num int not null,
  primary key (tileset_id, s2_cell_id)
);
```

Additionally, I have another index on `tiles.tileset_segment_counts(tileset_id, s2_cell_id, num)`. The query I would like to run is

```
SELECT tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments
from cover.covering_s2_cell_ids cs
JOIN tiles.tileset_segment_counts tsc on tsc.s2_cell_id BETWEEN cs.s2_cell_min AND cs.s2_cell_max
WHERE cs.covering_id = 2
  and tsc.tileset_id = 1
  and num > 100
```

This runs relatively quickly and seems to be doing what I expect, leveraging the triple index to filter rows from `tiles.tileset_segment_counts`:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..1285012.81 rows=7919778 width=544) (actual time=0.039..20.139 rows=19305 loops=1)
  Output: tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments
  Buffers: shared hit=5150
  ->  Index Scan using covering_s2_cell_ids_covering_id_idx on cover.covering_s2_cell_ids cs  (cost=0.29..12.04 rows=157 width=16) (actual time=0.018..0.088 rows=157 loops=1)
        Output: cs.covering_id, cs.s2_cell_id, cs.s2_cell_min, cs.s2_cell_max
        Index Cond: (cs.covering_id = 2)
        Buffers: shared hit=4
  ->  Index Scan using tileset_segment_counts_tileset_id_s2_cell_id_num_idx on tiles.tileset_segment_counts tsc  (cost=0.43..7680.28 rows=50444 width=544) (actual time=0.006..0.075 rows=123 loops=157)
        Output: tsc.tileset_id, tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments, tsc.num
        Index Cond: ((tsc.tileset_id = 1) AND (tsc.s2_cell_id >= cs.s2_cell_min) AND (tsc.s2_cell_id <= cs.s2_cell_max) AND (tsc.num > 100))
        Buffers: shared hit=5146
Planning time: 0.156 ms
Execution time: 23.760 ms
```

The problem occurs if I increase `num` to be a larger value. Let's say I use greater than 1000, which is a more restrictive query on that table, the query planner opts to use a sequential scan and filter of the large `tiles.tileset_segment_counts` table instead:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..405447.61 rows=1624688 width=1111) (actual time=4656.731..6367.624 rows=6185 loops=1)
  Output: tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments
  Join Filter: ((tsc.s2_cell_id >= cs.s2_cell_min) AND (tsc.s2_cell_id <= cs.s2_cell_max))
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 14430122
  Buffers: shared hit=142735
  ->  Seq Scan on tiles.tileset_segment_counts tsc  (cost=0.00..149546.77 rows=93135 width=1111) (actual time=0.119..214.902 rows=91951 loops=1)
        Output: tsc.tileset_id, tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments, tsc.num
        Filter: ((tsc.num > 1000) AND (tsc.tileset_id = 1))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 362013
        Buffers: shared hit=142731
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..12.82 rows=157 width=16) (actual time=0.000..0.030 rows=157 loops=91951)
        Output: cs.s2_cell_min, cs.s2_cell_max
        Buffers: shared hit=4
        ->  Index Scan using covering_s2_cell_ids_covering_id_idx on cover.covering_s2_cell_ids cs  (cost=0.29..12.04 rows=157 width=16) (actual time=0.015..0.052 rows=157 loops=1)
              Output: cs.s2_cell_min, cs.s2_cell_max
              Index Cond: (cs.covering_id = 2)
              Buffers: shared hit=4
Planning time: 0.152 ms
Execution time: 6368.822 ms
```

My thought is that the planner should be even more likely to want to use an index scan on tileset_segment_counts in this case, because it is returning even less rows. I've made sure I vacuum analyzed the table after creating the index. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I don't understand why having this more restrictive predicate would push the planner towards using the Join Filter + sequential scan over the index condition.

-- EDIT --
With `enable_seqscan` and `enable_material` set to `OFF`, the query uses either an index scan or a bitmap heap scan and runs fast (below for num > 1000):

```
Nested Loop  (cost=1010.05..744541.04 rows=1624688 width=1111) (actual time=0.048..8.272 rows=6185 loops=1)
  Output: tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments
  Buffers: shared hit=2353
  ->  Index Scan using covering_s2_cell_ids_covering_id_idx on cover.covering_s2_cell_ids cs  (cost=0.29..12.04 rows=157 width=16) (actual time=0.018..0.076 rows=157 loops=1)
        Output: cs.covering_id, cs.s2_cell_id, cs.s2_cell_min, cs.s2_cell_max
        Index Cond: (cs.covering_id = 2)
        Buffers: shared hit=4
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tiles.tileset_segment_counts tsc  (cost=1009.77..4638.74 rows=10348 width=1111) (actual time=0.013..0.035 rows=39 loops=157)
        Output: tsc.tileset_id, tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments, tsc.num
        Recheck Cond: ((tsc.tileset_id = 1) AND (tsc.s2_cell_id >= cs.s2_cell_min) AND (tsc.s2_cell_id <= cs.s2_cell_max) AND (tsc.num > 1000))
        Heap Blocks: exact=1688
        Buffers: shared hit=2349
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tileset_segment_counts_tileset_id_s2_cell_id_num_idx  (cost=0.00..1007.18 rows=10348 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=39 loops=157)
              Index Cond: ((tsc.tileset_id = 1) AND (tsc.s2_cell_id >= cs.s2_cell_min) AND (tsc.s2_cell_id <= cs.s2_cell_max) AND (tsc.num > 1000))
              Buffers: shared hit=661
Planning time: 0.156 ms
Execution time: 9.492 ms
```

The same is true if I only set `enable_material` to off and leave seq scans on. However, setting only `enable_seqscan = OFF` runs slowly and looks exactly like the slow query above (2nd plan), but instead of a sequential scan it uses an index or bitmap heap scan:

```
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tiles.tileset_segment_counts tsc  (cost=43731.56..178253.16 rows=93135 width=1111) (actual time=41.738..105.038 rows=91951 loops=1)
      Output: tsc.tileset_id, tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments, tsc.num
      Recheck Cond: ((tsc.tileset_id = 1) AND (tsc.num > 1000))
      Heap Blocks: exact=28833
      Buffers: shared hit=38069
      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tileset_segment_counts_tileset_id_s2_cell_id_num_idx  (cost=0.00..43708.27 rows=93135 width=0) (actual time=36.765..36.765 rows=91951 loops=1)
            Index Cond: ((tsc.tileset_id = 1) AND (tsc.num > 1000))
            Buffers: shared hit=9236
```

I understand this is a temporary solution; how do I go about making the planner realize this on its own? Is this a matter of costs being way off?

-- EDIT #2 --

Updated the first query plan in the first edit to use `num > 1000` to be consistent.

Additionally, I tried setting the global default_statistics_target to the max value (`10000`), vacuum analyzing everything, and rerunning. The query planner still uses the slower method of doing a sequential scan with a join filter that takes roughly 6 seconds.

What's even more baffling is if I introduce another table in the join, it coaxes the planner to use the faster method, regardless of the stats target or `enable_material` setting:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)
SELECT tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments
from public.markets d 
join cover.covering_s2_cell_ids cs on d.default_covering_id = cs.covering_id
JOIN tiles.tileset_segment_counts tsc on tsc.s2_cell_id BETWEEN cs.s2_cell_min AND cs.s2_cell_max
WHERE d.id = 2 
  and tsc.tileset_id = 1
  and num > 1000

Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..99387.70 rows=1021667 width=1108) (actual time=0.033..7.860 rows=6185 loops=1)
  Output: tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments
  Buffers: shared hit=2524
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..147.85 rows=100 width=16) (actual time=0.017..0.162 rows=157 loops=1)
        Output: cs.s2_cell_min, cs.s2_cell_max
        Buffers: shared hit=8
        ->  Seq Scan on public.markets d  (cost=0.00..5.56 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: d.id, d.name, d.neilsen_id, d.market_key, d.default_covering_id, d.enabled
              Filter: (d.id = 2)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 204
              Buffers: shared hit=3
        ->  Index Scan using covering_s2_cell_ids_pkey on cover.covering_s2_cell_ids cs  (cost=0.29..141.29 rows=100 width=20) (actual time=0.006..0.072 rows=157 loops=1)
              Output: cs.covering_id, cs.s2_cell_id, cs.s2_cell_min, cs.s2_cell_max
              Index Cond: (cs.covering_id = d.default_covering_id)
              Buffers: shared hit=5
  ->  Index Scan using tileset_segment_counts_tileset_id_s2_cell_id_num_idx on tiles.tileset_segment_counts tsc  (cost=0.42..890.23 rows=10217 width=1108) (actual time=0.004..0.031 rows=39 loops=157)
        Output: tsc.tileset_id, tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments, tsc.num
        Index Cond: ((tsc.tileset_id = 1) AND (tsc.s2_cell_id >= cs.s2_cell_min) AND (tsc.s2_cell_id <= cs.s2_cell_max) AND (tsc.num > 1000))
        Buffers: shared hit=2516
Planning time: 0.416 ms
Execution time: 9.010 ms
```

Truly at a loss

-- EDIT #3 --

Adding an index on `cover.covering_s2_cell_ids(covering_id, s2_cell_min, s2_cell_max)` does make the query run faster, but is still much slower than expected:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..267283.27 rows=1602272 width=1107) (actual time=68.918..411.856 rows=6185 loops=1)
  Output: tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments
  Buffers: shared hit=340825 read=3810
  ->  Seq Scan on tiles.tileset_segment_counts tsc  (cost=0.00..149528.89 rows=91850 width=1107) (actual time=0.010..213.931 rows=91951 loops=1)
        Output: tsc.tileset_id, tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments, tsc.num
        Filter: ((tsc.num > 1000) AND (tsc.tileset_id = 1))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 362013
        Buffers: shared hit=138924 read=3807
  ->  Index Only Scan using covering_s2_cell_ids_covering_id_s2_cell_min_s2_cell_max_idx on cover.covering_s2_cell_ids cs  (cost=0.29..1.11 rows=17 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=91951)
        Output: cs.covering_id, cs.s2_cell_min, cs.s2_cell_max
        Index Cond: ((cs.covering_id = 2) AND (cs.s2_cell_min <= tsc.s2_cell_id) AND (cs.s2_cell_max >= tsc.s2_cell_id))
        Heap Fetches: 0
        Buffers: shared hit=201901 read=3
Planning time: 0.372 ms
Execution time: 413.054 ms
```

Adding an index for tsc(tileset_id, num) improves it slightly, but is still slow. I should note that the subquery on the covering table will only match around 157 rows. It seems the difference between the fast (~10ms) and the slow/medium queries is the order in which the loops are occurring. Notice that in this latest query, we have to perform 91951 loops of the index scan on the covering table. In the fast queries, we first find the rows that match the covering (157 rows), and then only have to perform 157 index scans on the tileset table. I'm going to try tweaking cost estimates because the planning is clearly over-estimating the cost of the fast query.

Comment: Um, yes, I don't see the light either at first glance. Does the plan for the slow query change if you set `enable_material` and `enable_seqscan` to `off`? Can you post that plan for comparison? Did you set any of the `*_cost` parameters to a nonstandard value?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you for the reply, edited above with the plans. Seems like the materialization is the culprit, but I don't know how to get the planner to recognize that organically

Comment: The misestimate is at fault, but I don't yet understand how. Could you post a slow and a fast plan for the same value for the `tsc.num` cut-off, i.e. change nothing but `enable_material`? Then it is easier to compare numbers. Do the estimates improve if you increase `default_statistics_target` before `ANALYZE`? If yes, that would be the solution.

Comment: I can't tell if the estimates are improving, but it seems like they are not since it still selects the slower method; see edits above

Comment: It seems to me that `s2_cell_min bigint,
  s2_cell_max bigint,` are actually a range. The range is part of the shared key-elements between the two tables. IMHO, there should *at least* be an index on each of them (possibly combined with the other shared key) In short : `s2_cell_min, s2_cell_max` are *more or less* the target for a foreign key. from the tsc-table.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing @joop's idea of using an(int8)range for the minmax (these are searchable by an index)

---

```
create table covering_s2_cell_ids (
  covering_id int -- references coverings(id) on delete cascade
  , s2_cell_id bigint
  -- , s2_cell_min bigint
  -- , s2_cell_max bigint
  , cellminmax int8range NOT NULL -- << HERE
  , primary key (covering_id, s2_cell_id)
);

CREATE INDEX ON covering_s2_cell_ids USING GIST(cellminmax); -- << HERE


create table tileset_segment_counts (
  tileset_id int -- references tilesets(id) on delete cascade
  , s2_cell_id bigint not null
  , segments jsonb not null
  , num int not null
  , primary key (tileset_id, s2_cell_id)
);

CREATE index on tileset_segment_counts(tileset_id, s2_cell_id, num);

VACUUM ANALYZE covering_s2_cell_ids;
VACUUM ANALYZE tileset_segment_counts;

EXPLAIN
SELECT tsc.s2_cell_id, tsc.segments
from covering_s2_cell_ids cs
JOIN tileset_segment_counts tsc
        -- on tsc.s2_cell_id BETWEEN cs.s2_cell_min AND cs.s2_cell_max
        on tsc.s2_cell_id <@ cs.cellminmax -- << HERE
WHERE cs.covering_id = 2
  and tsc.tileset_id = 1
  and num > 100
  ;
```

---

Queryplan(no data):

---

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=3.24..9.61 rows=1 width=40)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tileset_segment_counts tsc  (cost=1.22..3.34 rows=2 width=40)
         Recheck Cond: ((tileset_id = 1) AND (num > 100))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tileset_segment_counts_tileset_id_s2_cell_id_num_idx  (cost=0.00..1.22 rows=2 width=0)
               Index Cond: ((tileset_id = 1) AND (num > 100))
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on covering_s2_cell_ids cs  (cost=2.02..3.13 rows=1 width=32)
         Recheck Cond: ((tsc.s2_cell_id <@ cellminmax) AND (covering_id = 2))
         ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=2.02..2.02 rows=1 width=0)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on covering_s2_cell_ids_cellminmax_idx  (cost=0.00..0.66 rows=6 width=0)
                     Index Cond: (tsc.s2_cell_id <@ cellminmax)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on covering_s2_cell_ids_pkey  (cost=0.00..1.21 rows=6 width=0)
                     Index Cond: (covering_id = 2)
(12 rows)
```

Comment: I get something [pretty different](https://gist.github.com/thegeebe/22bb846fc99c44b6b99bc50dc21e46c1) once populating with data (using num > 1000 for consistency)

Comment: And what is your setting for `random_page_cost` ?

Comment: My costs were set to defaults, so `random_page_cost = 4.0` and `seq_page_cost=1.0`. I am running on AWS RDS with a general purpose SSD. Setting `random_page_cost = 1.1` triggers the fast query with the full data loaded! Seems like other costs are still wildly inaccurate. The slow query has a cost of 405k, while the fast query with `random_page_cost=1.1` has a cost of 319k but runs almost 1000x faster.

Comment: And indeed, this seems to only stave off the problem transiently; increasing the `num` parameter will eventually revert back to the slow plan, even though (by setting `enable_material=OFF`) I see that it is much faster to use the fast one.

Comment: but: WHY DIDNT' YOU SAY SO IN THE FIRST PLACE... these tags exist. for a reason.